# navbar item allign bottom with logo

Tags: html, css, nav

I create one the Nav and put the logo on the top left, as the logo size is bigger, all of nav item now place on top left, can I know how to move them into bottom / centre?
Here is nav bar code

```
<div class="full-width">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 align-items-start">

        <img src="~/resources/images/projectLogo.jpg" alt="St Mary School" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">

        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" style="align-self:flex-end">Lesson School Project</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1" >
                <li class="nav-item" >
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="Index" >Lesson Search</a>
                </li>                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="PureChart">Result Chart</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </nav>
</div>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Please add the css also to the question, or mention the name of library.

Comment: try to replace ``align-items-start`` to ``align-items-center`` OR ``align-items-end``

Comment: can I know which tag need to add ? In Div element or ul element ?

Answer (score 0):

replace `align-items-start` to `align-items-center` in nav tag.